# Access images stored in public directory via routes

Tags: php, laravel

I want to access an image stored in the public folder in laravel by routing in case to search for image if exists in my public folder or not, here is my code so far:

**api.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'images', 'middleware' => 'cors'], function () {
Route::get('itemsImages/{imagename}','ManagerController@itemImage');
});
```

**ManagerController.php**

```
public function itemImage($imagename)
{
    // Check if file exists in storage directory
    $file_path = public_path() .'/images/itemsImages/'.$imagename;
    if (file_exists($file_path))
        return Response::download($file_path);
    else
        dd($file_path);
        //does not exist
}
```

But that code doesn't work and can't even access the route, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: do you registered your middleware?

Comment: Yes of course I did.

Comment: Check for errors on `laravel.log` and also check for the return code and message you get when trying to access the url. Then post here the results if possible.

Comment: Can you please mention the required path ? which you are tring to get .

Comment: try after changing url and then `dd` filename in method.

Comment: Here is the url `http://localhost:8000/images/itemsImages/2.jpg`, it returns 404 instead of dumping the `file_path` but if the image exists it shows the image

Comment: try `http://localhost:8000/api/images/itemsImages/2.jpg`, you are including the route on `api.php` that includes that prefix by default.

Comment: oh yes makes sense, but where should I move my code if I don't want to include the api in the route?

Comment: Put your api.php code in web.php file and then try.

Comment: @EmeraldQuasar you can either add your route to web.php or delete the prefix api from the api routes on `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`

Comment: Your code works in my environment, however, it won't enter the `Controller` if the file exists. Try enter a non-exist file path.

Comment: Yes the problem occurs when the file is not exists and that is the point of the routes from the beginning, it returns 505.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work,

```
Route::get('itemsImages/{filename}', function ($filename)
{
  $path = app_path('public/images/itemsImages') . '/' . $filename;
  $response = null;
  if (file_exists($path))
  {
    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);      
  }
  else
  {
    dd($path);
    //does not exist
  }
  return $response;
})->name('route.name');
```

I haven't tested the code above so tell me if works for you.

Comment: Well it returns 200 with the image path, it doesn't show the image itself

Comment: You can display the image like this `<img src={{ route('route.name', 'image.jpg') }}>`

Comment: Wherever you want to display the image in your blade file for example

Comment: well I am not using the blade, I am using this solution because if the image is not in that server then I am going to redirect into other one so the blade solution won't work for this case.

Comment: Well if you are saying that the function return 200 with the image path, that mean that the file exists and with that response you can display the image, is that what you asked in your fist commentary, if not it will execute the dd() function and you can play with that to do whatever you want.

Comment: It returns 200 even if the file does not exist, also if the file is there it execute the dd() in both cases.

Comment: That is interesting, can you try now with the new edits.

Comment: well I think I know where is the error, I fix it with this line of code                          
 `if( File::exists(public_path($path)))` now the image displayed if exists